# Flutter: Make a custom bottom bar sliding up when it appears

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, navbar

I am trying to design a music playlist page. So far I am able to create a listview with song cards. When I click on any song, a custom bottom bar appears and the audio starts playing. However, I just hold a state with boolean and show the bottom bar according to that. Instead, I want it to appear like sliding up and reach to the position. Let say in 0.5 seconds.

I have a custom NavBar class

```
class NavBar extends StatefulWidget
```

And I use this class in build similar to:

```
return Column(
  children: [
    SizedBox(
      height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.5,
      hild: SlidingBanners(),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Lists(),
    ),
    NavBar()
  ],
);
```

How can I such animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a SizeTransition widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizeTransition-class.html

> "SizeTransition acts as a ClipRect that animates either its width or
> its height, depending upon the value of axis. The alignment of the
> child along the axis is specified by the axisAlignment."

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return SizeTransition(
  sizeFactor: CurvedAnimation(
    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    parent: _animationController,
  ),
  child: Container(height: 100, color: Colors.blue)
);
}
```

init animation controller in stateful widgets initState()

```
  @override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_animationController = AnimationController(
    vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
  }
```

Make sure your stateful widget uses SingleTickerProviderStateMixin

```
class _NavBarState extends State<NavBar>
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
late AnimationController _animationController;
```

then open and close with

```
_animationController.forward()
_animationController.reverse()
```

You can pass the _animationController into the NavBar widget's constructor from its parent if you want the parent to control the animation.

Alternatively you can use an AnimatedContainer widget and setState with its height 0 or 100 depending on if Nav should be shown. This becomes a problem for some widgets that cannot be squished to height of 0 though and I would not recommend for any container that contains anything but text

Comment: so my aim is to show the bottom bar when a song in the list is tapped. In this case, should I pass the controller from the parent? I do not understand the forward(), reverse() usage here.

Comment: @nondefinite yes exactly! Pass the animation controller in from the parent as part of NavBar's constructor. Then, when you tap a song list in your parent you can call .forward/.reverse on that controller and it will animate the nav bar

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use a `SnackBar` widget. Since it's automatically animated, you wouldn't want to worry about manually animating the bottom bar. You can insert your Audio Player (bottom bar) widget to the `child` of the `SizedBox`.

The bottom bar is made visible by,

`ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);`

This bottom bar is dismissed (hidden) by dragging down or by,

`ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();`

There maybe many other solutions as well to this, but reading your question, I hope this is what you wanted.

```
return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          final snackBar = SnackBar(
            duration: Duration(days: 365),
            content: SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              //insert your audio player widget here
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text("YOUR AUDIOPLAYER WIDGET HERE"),
                  Text("Audio Controls Here"),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
                    },
                    child: Text("Audio Player Minimize"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
        },
        child: Text('Open Audio Player'),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: this is definitely not ideal. You shouldn't call .showSnackBar within the build itself because on rebuilds it will be shown multiple times. A snackbar is for short popup display of information, not an entire toolbar widget

Comment: @BradenBagby thanks for the feedback. But in the official documentation, it is called within the `build()`. https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/snackbars. I do agree that snackbars are for short popups, but thought maybe usable here.

Comment: the docs have the showSnackbar() being called on a button press callback which makes it outside of the build() call. Interesting technique though it is not really an ideal solution!